# With latest google api I am getting null Access Token with GoogleAuthUtil

Tags: android, google-authentication

Hello I am getting null Access Token with latest google API I dont what am i doing wrong. Please help..

```
Token=GoogleAuthUtil.getToken( MainActivity.this, mGoogleApiClient.getAccountName(), "oauth2:" + SCOPES)
```

the token is null here..

Here is the code

```
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken( MainActivity.this, mGoogleApiClient.getAccountName(), "oauth2:" + SCOPES);
E/RetrieveAccessToken: Unknown
private class RetrieveTokenTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
String accountName = params[0];
String scopes = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login";

try {
token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), accountName,scopes);
// Log.e("token",token);
// Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"token "+token,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} catch (IOException e) {
Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
} catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT);
} catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
return token;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
super.onPostExecute(s);
// Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"token "+token,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// Log.w("token",token);

Intent google_intent=new Intent(Login2.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(google_intent);
}
}
```

Also i am getting the account name but why not the access token?

Comment: The value which I am getting with api is null actually when i checked.

Comment: E/RetrieveAccessToken: Unknown

Comment: Have you download the json file ?

Comment: Are you asking about config file or json file downloaded from google dev console??

Comment: Of course, it is mandatory